# How to get configuration options programmatically?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Does someone know a way to find out all configuration options from an ExtJS control programmatically? I do mean options like width, height etc. as described in the EXTJS documentation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access the config options that were passed to a particular Component, then you can access these from `this.initialConfig`.

If you want to get a list of all possible config options that could be passed, then this can't really be done from within ExtJS framework itself. Basically you are limited by the fact that not all config options are listed in prototype - many which default to undefined are just checked for programmatically.

You can extract this data from Ext JS doc-comments using [jsduck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck) to export the docs in JSON format, from which you can filter out the config options.

Comment: Thx. But I was afraid of this answer. So for now I have to write a workaround for testing each control against its special configuration list.

Comment: Why would you want to test components against their configuration list? I don't even really understand what you mean by it.

Comment: As you know you can create controls from markup. A script interprets markup attributes and collects only valid options and its values. Markup code can easily designed by a html coder without really knowing anything about extjs. Especially in the context of a CMS.